# Using Python Pillow in front-end Angular

Tags: javascript, python, python-imaging-library, image-resizing

I'm trying to use the Python Pillow library's resize function from within a front-end Angular 8 project.

While I know there are alternatives like OpenCV and HTML5 canvas but based on feedback, these alternatives won't work, with my use case. That is because the AI model that my front-end will be interacting with uses Pillow to model and there are some fundamental differences in the way Pillow does resize as compared to OpenCV and Canvas.

Differences between library resize:

- https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/2718
- https://towardsdatascience.com/image-read-and-resize-with-opencv-tensorflow-and-pil-3e0f29b992be

Since I have not been able to find a previously built JavaScript port for Pillow, I assume that I would need to do it on my own, I've explored several Python to JavaScript "Translators" like [Brython](https://brython.info/) and [Transcrypt](https://www.transcrypt.org/) but I understand they don't work well with external libraries (which Pillow requires).

Hence I decided to try my luck here to see if there have been anyone who has been in a similar situation and has a solution to my dilemma before I attempt to spend the hours porting Pillow and their respective libraries over to the dark side.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Would the [Imagemagik](https://www.npmjs.com/package/imagemagick) JavaScript library work for you?

Comment: Thanks John, do you happen to know if the way Imagemagik processes it's image resize is similar to Python's Pillow?

Comment: No sorry I don't.  I just know Imagemagick itself is something of a multitool for image processing, is cross platform, and has been around a long time.

Comment: For the record, I'm in the same situation - and it doesn't look like there's any good solution here for using Pillow client-side in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

PyScript is a newer solution which can compile libs to wasm for you, but it's extremely slow to start